# Invalid flavor in printing with java

Tags: java, jvm, printers

i trying to printing docs with java like this:

but in some computers its give me error:

```
INFO: Got an exception.
sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
```

in this line:

```
job.print(doc, attrs);
```

This is the code:

```
  public void printFiles(ArrayList<ByteArrayInputStream> files) throws PrintException, IOException {
        Native.loading.setText(Constants.PRINT_LOADING);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attrs.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
        attrs.add(new JobName(Constants.PRINT_JOB_NAME, null));

        long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double totalTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
        logger.info("PrintFiles time 1: " + totalTime);
        
        DocFlavor[] flavors = service.getSupportedDocFlavors();
        for(int i=0; i<flavors.length; i++)
        {
              logger.info("flavor " + i + ": " + flavors[i].toString());
        }
        
        logger.info("curFlavor: " + DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE.toString());
        
        if(service != null)
        {
              logger.info("Default Printer: " + service.getName());
              
              startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              
              PrintService selection = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200, services, service, null, attrs); 
              
              endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
              totalTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
              logger.info("PrintFiles time 2: " + totalTime);
              
              startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              if(selection != null)
              {
                    logger.info(selection.getName());

                    for(int i=0; i<files.size(); i++)
                    {
                          ByteArrayInputStream file = files.get(i);

                          DocPrintJob job = selection.createPrintJob();
                          Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(file, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
                          
                          job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintListener());
                          job.print(doc, attrs);

                          if(file != null)
                                file.close();
                    }
              }
              
              endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
              totalTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
              logger.info("PrintFiles time 3: " + totalTime);
        }
  }
```

i tried to print all the flavors that supported in my computer (that working) and in the another computer (that not working).

this is the flavors that supported in the working computer:

```
INFO: flavor 0: image/gif; class="[B"

INFO: flavor 1: image/gif; class="java.io.InputStream"

INFO: flavor 2: image/gif; class="java.net.URL"

INFO: flavor 3: image/jpeg; class="[B"

INFO: flavor 4: image/jpeg; class="java.io.InputStream"

INFO: flavor 5: image/jpeg; class="java.net.URL"

INFO: flavor 6: image/png; class="[B"

INFO: flavor 7: image/png; class="java.io.InputStream"

INFO: flavor 8: image/png; class="java.net.URL"

INFO: flavor 9: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"

INFO: flavor 10: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"

INFO: flavor 11: application/octet-stream; class="[B"

INFO: flavor 12: application/octet-stream; class="java.net.URL"

INFO: flavor 13: application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"

INFO: flavor 14: application/postscript; class="[B"

INFO: flavor 15: application/postscript; class="java.io.InputStream"

INFO: flavor 16: application/postscript; class="java.net.URL"
```

and this is the flavors in the not working computer:

```
INFO: flavor 0: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"

INFO: flavor 1: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"
```

I want to know why i have only 2 flavors in the printer? this printer working fine in this computer except java application.
how can i fix this code to working with all printers?

tnx